# Bad request from componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using Sortable (https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) to be able to drag and sort a list of items that I have. I want this to load on `componentDidMount` and the actual sort functionality works. However when it gets to the ajax request, I get a 400 bad request. I think it has something to do with the context that it is in but I thought I sorted that out.

When I simply leave out componentDidMount and just attach the function to the list item, the request works fine. The only thing that's stopping me from doing this is that the list item requires a click before Sortable loads.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
var ToDoList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {}
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.moveItem();
  },  
  moveItem: function(id){
    var el = document.getElementById('list');
    var sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
      onSort: function(evt) {
        var data = { todo_id: id, old_index: evt.oldIndex , new_index: evt.newIndex }

        $.ajax({
          url: "/todo/api/v1.0/move-task",
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          context: this,
          success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            var updated_todos = this.props.changeTodos(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  },
  render: function(){

    return ( <ul id="list">
      {this.props.todos.map((todo, index) => (
        <li onMouseDown={this.moveItem.bind(this, todo._id.$oid)} key={todo._id.$oid} data-id={todo._id.$oid} className={"list-item"}>
          <input checked={todo.complete} onChange={this.completeItem.bind(this, todo._id.$oid)} type="checkbox" />
          <div className={"item " + todo.complete }>{todo.item}</div>
          <div className="move">△▽</div>
          <div className="delete" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, todo._id.$oid)}>x</div>
        </li>
      ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: you call `this.moveItem();` without id

Comment: thought this was the case. how would I go about passing the id across to the `componentDidMount` function??

Comment: Why are you trying to move an item in componentDidMount()?  componentDidMount only gets called once. I can understand you maybe pre-loading the list in there, but moving one of the items doesn't seem to make sense. What is your intention there? What are you trying to do?  it will help find correct answer

Answer (score 0):

It is a context issue, try using bind, like so:

```
moveItem: function(id){
    var el = document.getElementById('list');
    var sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
      onSort: function(evt) {
        var data = { todo_id: id, old_index: evt.oldIndex , new_index: evt.newIndex }

        $.ajax({
          url: "/todo/api/v1.0/move-task",
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          context: this,
          success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            var updated_todos = this.props.changeTodos(data);
          }.bind(this)
        });
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
```

I would recommend moving towards ES6+ using Babel. Then you could use arrow functions where the context doesn't change (In addition to many other benefits). Here's a tutorial to get you started: https://blog.risingstack.com/the-react-way-getting-started-tutorial/

Comment: thanks for this. but it's still not working - i ended up passing a long this = that at one point to pass the context and that didn't work either. but thanks for the tutorial on es6. I really need to get up to speed with it.